# Discord music bot with lavalink (Music from spotify)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
d:\Python\node_modules\lavasfy\dist\Client.js:59
                return Promise.reject(new Error("Invalid Spotify client."));
                                      ^

Error: Invalid Spotify client.
    at LavasfyClient.requestToken (d:\Python\node_modules\lavasfy\dist\Client.js:59:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.exec (d:\Python\MusicBotJs\src\listeners\ready.js:6:29)

Node.js v17.4.0
```

How to I fix this error (I have entered the spotify client ID , Secret)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but you are probably using erela.js since it's a famous NodeJs library, in that case, you could use plugins like [erela.js-spotify](https://npmjs.com/package/erela.js-spotify), or you could use lavalink libraries that already have that implemented, like [fastlink](https://npmjs.com/package/fastlink).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31295831)

Comment: Maybe, but still the answer will be related to a npm (as a plugin for a Lavalink npm or as a Lavalink Wrapper).